# Probability problem Bayes

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

*In 80% of the cases a worker uses the subway to get to work. If he gets it there's an 3/4 probability to get to work on time. In average 4 out of 6 days he gets to work on time.Today he didn't get to work. Whats the probability he took the subway?*

I was thinking I could have two events A:"He gets to work at time" B:"He takes the subway" and maybe use Bayes but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \{\text{arrive on time}\}\, B = \{\text{takes train}\}$. Then you are interested in calculating the event

$$\mathbf{P}[ B \, | \, A^c]$$

where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$,i.e. $A^c = \{\text{does not arrive on time}\}$.

From the information you give above

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[B] & = \frac45 \\
\mathbf{P}[A \, | \, B] & = \frac34 \\
\mathbf{P}[A] & = \frac46 = \frac23
\end{align*}
and from these we can deduce
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[A^c \, | \, B] & = 1-\mathbf{P}[A \, | \, B] =  \frac14 \\
\mathbf{P}[A^c]\ &= 1- \mathbf{P}[A] =\frac13
\end{align*}

Now we are in a position to use Bayes Rule

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[B \, | \, A^c] & = \mathbf{P}[A^c \, | \, B] \frac{\mathbf{P}[B]}{\mathbf{P}[A^c]} \\
& = \left( \frac14 \times \frac45 \right) \big/ \left( \frac13 \right) \\
& = \frac35
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much I understood it now just one small q at P[Ac|B]=1−P[Ac|B] you meant 1-P[A|B]?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Letting A and B be as you described, we have 
\begin{equation}
    P(A|B) = 3/4,
\end{equation}

and we are interested in
\begin{equation}
    P(B|A^c) = \frac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(A)}.
\end{equation}

Recall that for any two events X, Y,
\begin{equation}
    P(X) = P(X \cap Y) + P(X \cap Y^c).
\end{equation}